# Can't write CLR type C# error when trying to update table

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

I have a project with several `DataGridView` components. Data tables in the data base contain some foreign keys in those tables, so I need to swap them for corresponding values (for example faculty_id to faculty_title).

So I made a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` for those. I have faculty_id foreign key in several tables, and the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` are made literally the same for all of them, but it seems, that it works fine only on one of tables.

Code of one `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` :

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn students_faculty_cbc = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
            {
                HeaderText = "Fakultate",
                DataSource = attendanceRecording.Tables["faculties"],
                DisplayMember = "faculty_title",
                ValueMember = "faculty_id",
                DataPropertyName = "faculty_id"
            };
```

So now, when I add this column to `DataGridView`, I have a column with dropdowns in each row, with possible values of faculty_title.

When I change it, and try to sync changes with database, I get an error:
 `System.InvalidCastException: 'Can't write CLR type System.String with handler type Int32Handler'`

The query also is very similar to the one from the table, where this `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` works just fine. Nothing extra is added or nothing is missing.
So, for example:

- Query, with which I get no error:

```
NpgsqlCommand update_audiences = new NpgsqlCommand("UPDATE audiences SET audience_number = @audience_number, faculty_id = @faculty_id WHERE audience_id = @id", conn);
            update_audiences.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@audience_number", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 5, "audience_number"));
            update_audiences.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@faculty_id", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "faculty_id"));
            update_audiences.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@id", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "audience_id"));
```

- Query, which gives me the error:

```
NpgsqlCommand update_students = new NpgsqlCommand("UPDATE students SET " +
                                                              "student_name = @student_name, student_surname = @student_surname, matriculation_number = @matriculation_number, faculty_id = @faculty_id, " +
                                                              "course = @course, phone_number = @phone_number, email = @email, gender = @gender WHERE student_id = @id", conn);
            update_students.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@student_name", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 50, "student_name"));
            update_students.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@student_surname", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 60, "student_surname"));
            update_students.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@matriculation_number", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 7, "matriculation_number"));
            update_students.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@faculty_id", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "faculty_id"));
            update_students.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@course", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "course"));
            update_students.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@phone_number", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, 8, "phone_number"));
            update_students.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@email", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 50, "email"));
            update_students.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@gender", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 15, "gender"));
            update_students.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@id", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "student_id"));
```

I cant spot the problem here. Maybe someone can tell me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This error tells me that whenever your setting the value of the facility_id parameter, the DataGridViewComboBox is returning a string. I can’t seem to find where you set the parameter value, but you likely should force-parse it to an integer.

Comment: @S.Walker if you meant about faculty_id parameter for not-working query, then I set it like this - ```update_students.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@faculty_id", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "faculty_id"));```

Comment: @S.Walker and i didnt quite get, what did you meant with ''you likely should force-parse it to an integer.''
I need to take that value from ```ComboBoxColumn``` and convert it back to corresponding faculty_id?

Comment: @JohnG That format is used in, e.g., Update() commands applied to a Datadapter, to signify that the values are not added manually, but taken from the specified SourceColumn of the object that's being updated (DataSet/DataTable). See the BatchInsertUpdate example in [Updating Data Sources with DataAdapters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters) and the Remarks section of [DataAdapter.Update(DataSet) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.update).

Comment: @Jimi … Great info… I did not know this. I am guessing another useful reason to use a `DataAdapter`. I will research more. Thanks for the great info.